# Wix creates a Bootstrapper folder - is it needed?

Tags: build, wix, installation, setup-project, bootstrapper

When I build my Wix project, it creates a Bootstrapper folder in the output directory (i.e. `bin\Debug\Bootstrapper`). Is that folder actually needed by the installer, or is it just an intermediate directory? That is, do I need to ship the Bootstrapper folder along with the installer? I assume not, but....?

Thanks.

Comment: WiX doesn't use a bootstrapper by default. What version are you using? Is your project using prerequisites or Burn?